# Can a one-dimensional shape have volume?

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, dimensional-analysis

Today, I decided I would try to generalize a formula to find area and volume of a hypercube. The formulae I came up with are as follows:

$n$ = number of dimensions

$L$ = side length

Surface area = $2nL^{n-1}$

Volume = $L^n$

So, naturally, I decided to make a table of surface area and volume of hypercubes, and using the formula, I found that the volume of a one-dimensional shape is two. This seems illogical, but then again, to me it's hard to conceptualize things in dimensions other than 2 or 3.

Can someone help me out here, and maybe update my formulae if needed?

Edit: I figured out the whole one-dimensional thing, but now I'm having trouble with the surface area in two dimensions. If $L = 2$, then shouldn't $A = 4$? I only get 8 using the equation.

Comment: What values did you use for $L$ and $n$ to get $L^{n} = 2$?

Comment: L = 2, and n = 1.

Comment: Well the "1-dimensional volume" (i.e., length) of a line of length 2 is 2. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @RobArthan, nevermind. I figured it out, I was just over-thinking it.

Comment: In $n$-dimension, the 'surface area' you referred to is the $n-1$-dimension measure of the boundary of the hypercube. When $n = 2$, what you called  'surface area' is the perimeter of the solid square of side $2$ and has value $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the table of values for $L = 1, 2$ and $n = 1, 2, 3$.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
L & n & \mbox{Area} = 2nL^{n-1} & \mbox{Volume} = L^n & \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 6 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 8 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 24 & 8 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 12 & 9 \\
3 & 3 & 72 & 27 \\
\end{array}
$$

So for example, with $L = n = 2$ (the case in your "Edit") you get a surface area of $8$, because the sum of the lengths of the $4$ sides of a square with side length $2$ is $8$.

Note that the surface areas when $n = 1$ need to be taken with a pinch of salt - we are pretending for convenience that the $0$-dimensional volume of a point is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. If you didn't assume the the volume of a point is one, then the area would be zero for a one-dimensional shape, correct?

Comment: Taking the $0$-dimensional volume of a point as $1$ gives us the nice property that the area in the case $L = 1$ is the number of facets (i.e., $(n-1)$-cubes that make up the surface of the $n$-cube for all $n \ge 1$.We could adopt a different convention, but this one is convenient.